# Postgres function overloading with defaults - is my function uncallable?

Tags: sql, postgresql, overloading

Suppose I create two functions like so:

```
create function test() returns int
as 
$$ 
    select 1::int
$$
language sql;



create function test(int default 5) returns int
as 
$$ 
    select $1
$$
language sql;
```

If I do this:

```
select * from test();
```

I get an error saying that `function test() is not unique`.  Is there any way to call the first function above?  Similarly, how can I call the second function above using the default value?

Comment: I expect you'd have the same problem in any programming language. Which function would you expect to be used and why, when both have effectively the same signature?

Comment: Honestly I was expecting an error from postgres at the time of the function's creation...and since I didn't get one I assumed I was missing something, and that the first function was still 'valid' in a sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - there's not a way and it is documented:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-func.html

> Functions that have default values for parameters are considered to
>   match any call that omits zero or more of the defaultable parameter
>   positions. *If more than one such function matches a call, the one
>   appearing earliest in the search path is used.* **If there are two or
>   more such functions in the same schema with identical parameter types
>   in the non-defaulted positions (which is possible if they have
>   different sets of defaultable parameters), the system will not be able
>   to determine which to prefer**, and so an “ambiguous function call”
>   error will result if no better match to the call can be found.

Emphasis mine.